# Different modes for encryption in Laravel allowed

Tags: security, encryption, laravel, laravel-4

What are the different Security modes available on Laravel 4 when using the `Crypt::encrypt` method. The [Security](http://laravel.com/docs/security#encryption) documentation shows how to use the Crypt::setMode with `ctr` as the mode set. What are the other modes that can be used?

I did go through the source of the Encryption class and noticed that `cbc` is being set by default. Are there other modes that can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source code, it seems that you can use anything that [PHP's mcrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) supports. There are two pretty extensive lists of [Available Cyphers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php) and 
[Available Modes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.constants.php).

Laravel 4.0.0 source code reference:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.0.0/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php#L79
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.0.0/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php#L245-L259